# Can I reconstitute a GroupByObject from an index and a list of groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe where the index are timestamps that are spaced 1 minute apart. I perform a `Groupby` to bin the data into groups of 10-minute windows:

```
compression = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
grouped_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=compression))
```

The problem is that pd.Grouper generates 10-minute groups where any of the group may not contain any data, meaning the group is empty.

When I now try to aggregate data I receive an error :

```
attribute_df[column_names] = grouped_df.agg(lambda x: np.log10(x[9] / x[0]))
```

Error:

> Exception has occurred: IndexError
> index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Are there ways within the `GroupBy` to ignore empty groups? Or in the `Agg` function to skip empty groups? I prefer not do check for the group size within the lambda function as this would considerably slow down this and other Aggregation functions. I would hate to have to iterate over each group manually.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# don't forget the column name
attribute_df[column_names] = grouped_df['Col_Name'].agg(lambda x: np.log10(x[9] / x[0]) if len(x) else np.NaN)
```

Comment: Thanks, though I was aware of that as mentioned at the end of my question, and try to avoid a condition within the lambda, but I guess its already breaking the "contract" in pandas by using the lambda expression. Thanks